# String-keyed HashMap in rust?

Tags: hashmap, rust

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use a HashMap with a key of type `~str` idiomatically. For example,

```
let mut map: hashmap::HashMap<~str, int> = hashmap::HashMap::new();
// Inserting is fine, I just have to copy the string.
map.insert("hello".to_str(), 1);

// If I look something up, do I really need to copy the string?
// This works:
map.contains_key(&"hello".to_str());

// This doesn't: as expected, I get
// error: mismatched types: expected `&~str` but found `&'static str` (expected &-ptr but found &'static str)
map.contains_key("hello");
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6095) bug report, I tried

```
map.contains_key_equiv("hello");
```

but got

```
error: mismatched types: expected `&<V367>` but found `&'static str` (expected &-ptr but found &'static str)
```

I really don't understand this last message; does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This question is now obsolete; thanks to the `Borrow` trait, a simple translation of the code to current syntax and method names will work just fine, with no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of `contains_key_equiv` is:

```
pub fn contains_key_equiv<Q:Hash + Equiv<K>>(&self, key: &Q) -> bool
```

That is, it takes a reference to something that is `Equiv`alent to `K == ~str`. So to check for a `&str` (which is `Equiv`alent to `~str`), we want a `& &str` (a reference to a string slice).

```
map.contains_key_equiv(&("hello"));

// or

map.contains_key_equiv(& &"hello");
```

(Note that these are equivalent, and are just required to get around the fact that `"foo" == &"foo"` are both `&str`s.)

Answer (score 4):

You have `HashMap<K, V>` with `~str` (an owned string) as `K`; thus, where it wants `&K` for `things`, that is `&~str`—a reference to an owned string. You, however, are passing it a reference to a static string (a string literal without any sigil [`&`, `~`, etc.], `"hello"`, is of type `&'static str`).

For string literals, do not use `.to_str()`; instead, prefix it with a `~`, as `~"hello"`. A string literal like that is of type `~str`. For a non-literal, you should typically use `.to_owned()` of a `&str`.

The eventual code can operate like this:

```
use std::hashmap::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut h = HashMap::new::<~str, int>();
    h.insert(~"foo", 42);
    printfln!("%?", h.find(&~"foo")); // => Some(&42)
    printfln!("%?", h.contains_key(&~"foo")); // => true

    // You don’t actually need the HashMap to own the keys (but
    // unless all keys are 'static, this will be likely to lead
    // to problems, so I don’t suggest you do it in reality)
    let mut h = HashMap::new::<&str, int>();
    h.insert("foo", 42);
    printfln!("%?", h.find(& &"foo")); // => Some(&42)
}
```

Observe that when you need a reference to a reference you can't do `&&` as that is the boolean AND operator; you need to do `&(&x)` or `& &x`.

(Note also that any issue from three months ago may not be current; I'm not certain of the current state of HashMap's comparison techniques—try both ways, with the correct types.)

Comment: This is no longer accurate as of rust 1.0

Comment: Yep. The HashMap API is much nicer now, as `get` and `contains_key` can take a type that is equivalent to the key type thanks to `Borrow`, and so you can just `h.get("foo")` instead of the old `h.find(&~"foo")` which performed an unnecessary heap allocation. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0899b611008ea9792aa653e882835c44 is an update of the code sample to use current techniques. However, I’m disinclined to update the answer as a whole, because it’s for a question that simply isn’t relevant in current Rust, thanks to this `Borrow` trait.